# Function to transform a dataframe is not working properly

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 x <- c(1,2,3)
 y <- c(4,5,5)

 df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Now I would like to run my dataframe through a function to deal with the 5 values.

So like

```
getRidOdNAs <- function(df){

  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){

    if(df$y[i] == 5){

       df$y[i] <- 0

    }
  }
 return(df)
 }
```

Now this works. But when I call my dataframe df afterwards I get again:

```
> df
  x y
  1 1 4
  2 2 5
  3 3 5
```

Any thoughts what I should do so get back the changed dataframe?

Comment: Save the result to a variable or rewrite over df. You can also use `df$y[df$y == 5] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `getRidOdNAs` does not modify the input `df` but rather outputs a new data frame that is a modified version of the input.  That output must be assigned to a variable or else it will be lost.  Running this code using the function in the question does work:

```
df.orig <- df # make a copy of df and store it in df.orig

df2 <- getRidOdNAs(df)
df2 # df2 is indeed a modified version of the input, df
##   x y
## 1 1 4
## 2 2 0
## 3 3 0

identical(df.orig, df) # df unchanged
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that this also works:

```
df3 <- transform(df, y = replace(y, y == 5, 0))

identical(df2, df3) # check that df2 and df3 are identical
## [1] TRUE
```

As does this:

```
df4 <- df # make a copy so we can avoid overwriting df
df4$y[df4$y == 5] <- 0  # overwrite df4

identical(df4, df2) # df4 is same as df2
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!